# Getting element in DOM after ajax call

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

There is a lot question and answers about that question, but I'm not being able to make it work for my case.

My extension gets the positions (1,2,...,100) on the scores pages of a game. When I first load the page I get the first 100 positions, but there are more pages, the problem is that the other pages are called with ajax and I cannot get them after the ajax call.

I came to conclusion that I could use **Mutation Observers** to detect changes in DOM, but I tried a lot of different codes and they all seem to not work.

My **manifest.json** file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Ogame Fleet Counter",
    "short_name": "OFC",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": { "16": "16.png",
               "48": "48.png",
               "128": "128.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "48.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches":[
                "https://*.ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=shipyard*",
                "https://*.ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=highscore"
            ],
            "js": ["js/jquery.js", "js/content.js"] 
        }
    ]
}
```

My **background.js** file:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "js/jquery.js" }, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "js/content.js" });
  });
});
var insertedNodes = [];
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
 mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
   for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++)
     insertedNodes.push(mutation.addedNodes[i]);
 })
});
observer.observe(document, { childList: true });
console.log(insertedNodes);
```

My extension consists in only **background.js**, the **content.js** (content script) and **jquery.js**.

I tried much more codes and tried changed my own, no luck. Could I use another method than **Mutation Observers** ? Adding onclick function in all buttons to trigger my content script maybe? Appreciate some help.

**Edit:** So I saw on the **DOM** that I need to catch: `<span class=" activePager">1</span>` changing, the number 1 there represents page one when I click on page two it changes to 2.

Answer (score 1):

You need use your Mutation Observer on content script, because changes are happens there.

After this, you can send these changes to the Background page and process it from there.

Comment: How do I process them on the background page?

Comment: You can send messages between BG page to Content Script. [Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) link is here. 
For example, you can send mutations from CS to BG page and them filter/store it there. 
It depends on the information, which you need to find.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've been messing with it for the last 3h... got some progress, getting an error on the message response from background.js `Cannot read property 'registered' of undefined` . But your answer helped me

Comment: You are welcome :)
You can also check a samples of [chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples), they are useful and can help.